# Спарсить ссылки из пагинации с помощью Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Добрый день.
Нужно с сайта https://itp.ne.jp/genre_dir/9570/pg/1/?sr=1&ngr=1&num=20 вытащить все ссылки из пагинации, их там около 250, и записать в массив. Скрипт около минуты пытается что то выполнить, в итоге глохнет, ничего не выводит и ошибок тоже. Делаю на локалке, использую curl и Simple HTML DOM.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function curl_get($url, $referer = 'https://www.google.ru/') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);
    return $out;
}

function pagination_url() {
    static $i = 1;
    $current_url = array();
    $current_url[$i] = 'https://itp.ne.jp/genre_dir/9570/pg/'.$i.'/?sr=1&ngr=1&num=20';

    $html = curl_get($current_url[$i]);
    $dom = str_get_html($html);

    $current_li = $dom->find('.bottomNav ul li[class=current]', 0);
    $next_li = $current_li->next_sibling ();
    $next_url = $next_li->find('a', 0)->attr;

    if (!empty($next_url['href']) && isset($next_url['href'])) {
        $i++;
        pagination_url();
    }
    return $current_url;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(pagination_url());
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: не уверен насчет области видимости static в php, но кажется все же `$i` у вас всегда 1. Вот и цикл вечный. Хотя даже с любой областью видимости она у вас все равно 1 будет.

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev: почему всегда 1? Если условие выполняется `$i` увеличивается на 1.

Comment: зачем парсить страницы/ссылки если вы знаете как они выглядят, и знаете их количество? Написано же у вас внизу что-то вроде "показаны 1-20 из 37638" итого 1882 страницы, но если указать номер больше 250, то не работает следовательно это программное ограничение. Так что там не около 250, а ровно 250. цикл от 1 до 250 сгенерит вам все ссылки подстановкой `$i`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev вы учебник почитайте сначала, чтобы быть уверенным.

Comment: около минуты и глохнет, это таймлимит на выполнение скорее всего. Хотя если уберете таймлимит, то получите еще что-нибдуь, ибо решение такое задачи с помощью рекурсии - не лучший способ. рекурсия вообще редко бывает хорошим способом решения задачи, есть альтернатива существует.

Comment: @teran страниц там не 1882, а 250, проверил. То что внизу "показаны 1-20 из 37638" первое это кол-во элементов на странице, а второе вообще не понятно что.
 _зачем парсить страницы/ссылки если вы знаете как они выглядят, и знаете их количество?_ как выглядят ссылки знаю, но количество ведь может поменяться, так что в перспективе цикл от 1 до 250 не очень хорошее решение.

Comment: @teran а как без рекурсии пройтись по всем ссылкам? Ничего другого придумать не могу(

Comment: прочитайте еще раз про искусственное ограничение числа просматриваемых страниц. Всегда можно запрашивать, например каждую 50ю страницу, и если она имеется, то генерить промежуточные ссылки вручную. Либо брать полный набор ссылок пагинации со страницы и сохранять все, а не по одной. Формально там не 250 страниц ограничение, а не более 5000 записей, ибо если вы укажите параметр _по 30 записей на страницу_, то отобразиться 166 страниц.

Answer (score 1):

На сайте присутствует ограничение на число просматриваемых элементов, и ограничено оно значением в `5000`. Рядом с пейджером указано число показанных записей и общее число элементов, например, `1-20件/37638件`. То что в начале показаны номера текущих записей (1-20) вроде очевидно, судя по тому, что символ `件` (в переводе *item*) присутствует в обоих частях, то означает он единицу измерения, т.е. `штук`. Можно изменить значение атрибута `num` в интервале 20-30 и на последней странице всегда будет число не превышающее 5000. Что подтверждает мысль об искусственном ограничении.

Так что на мой взгляд  набор URL можно сгенерировать просто в цикле:

```
define('PAGE_COUNT', 250);
define('URL_PATTERN', "https://itp.ne.jp/genre_dir/9570/pg/[pnum]/?sr=1&ngr=1&num=20");

$urls = [];
for($pnum = 1; $pnum <= PAGE_COUNT; $pnum++){
    $urls[] = str_replace( '[pnum]', $pnum, URL_PATTERN);
}

print_r($urls);
```

Что касается вашего кода.

- Скачивание страницы ресурсоемкая задача, и по времени и трафик гоняет. Время выполнения пхп-скрипта ограничено в `php.ini`. Можете увеличить, но качаться 250 страниц у вас будут долго.
- На странице приведено сразу 10 ссылок, то есть количество скачиваний можно сократить в 10 раз, обработав все ссылки со страницы
- Другим подходом будет сформировать несколько тестовых запросов на получение произвольной страницы. Например, 200. Если страница получена, то первые 200 ссылок можно формировать вручную. Это уменьшить количество скачиваний на этом интервале в 200 раз. В общем можно использовать метод деления отрезка пополам.
- Ваша рекурсия весьма легко переделывается в цикл. По факту вы не используете всю суть рекурсии в этой функции (не используете данные полученные в предыдущем вызове функции). Использование рекурсии вместо цикла просто будет требовать все больше и больше ресурсов. Обычно такое приводит к `StackOverflow` или нехватки памяти.
- Чтобы получить ссылку на следующую страницу не надо искать текущую в списке и брать следующую. В конце есть кнопка Следующая/Вперед/Далее `次へ`.
- Чтобы вытащить единственную нужную ссылку использование `HTML DOM` слишком трудозатратно. Эффективней найти нужный кусок текста и выдернуть ссылку с помощью регулярок или строковых функций.